# Breaking lines resulting from \mintinline or \Verb

Tags: luatex, verbatim, minted, code

I have come to a point where I really need a way to have LaTeX automatically break lines formatted as inline listings. I'm using the package `minted`. Here's a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\definecolor{bg}{rgb}{0.85, 0.85, 0.85}
\setmintedinline{bgcolor=bg}
\setmonofont{Courier New}
\begin{document}
    Hello world
    
    \mintinline{text}{aVeryLongStringaVeryLongStringaVeryLongStringaVeryLongStringaVeryLongStringaVeryLongStringaVeryLongStringaVeryLongString}
    
    \Verb[breaklines, breakanywhere]{aVeryLongStringaVeryLongStringaVeryLongStringaVeryLongStringaVeryLongStringaVeryLongStringaVeryLongStringaVeryLongString}
\end{document}
```

When compiling with `latexmk -lualatex -shell-escape test.tex`, the result is as follows:

[image]

According to the docs for `minted`, `breaklines` and `breakanywhere` are not available for `\mintinline`. I'm not sure about `breakbytoken`, but I'd be open to using it if it could potentially fix my problem.

There are two main issues logged in the `minted` repository that attempt to address this problem:

- https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/31
- https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/329

I read through both issues and it seems that the only viable workaround for now is to use `\Verb` instead of `\mintinline`. However there are a couple of problems with `\Verb` as far as I can tell:

- You cannot set a language (Python, C++) the same way you can with `\mintinline`
- You cannot set a `bgcolor`, which I like to have to clearly distinguish inline code from surrounding text.

There has got to be a way to achieve this using `\mintinline`? Any suggestions or ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in two steps:

The `breaklines` option does already work with `\mintinline`, but `breakanywhere` doesn't. If you look into `fvextra` at the implementation of this you can see that you can add this by adding `\FancyVerbBreakStart` and `\FancyVerbBreakStop` in `\minted@inputpyg`. We can patch this in with

```tex
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
% Patch minted to allow breakanywhere for \mintinline
\patchcmd \minted@inputpyg {%
  \FancyVerbFormatLine
}{%
  \FancyVerbFormatLine{%
    \strut\FancyVerbFormatText{\FancyVerbBreakStart##1\FancyVerbBreakStop}\strut%
  }%
  \@gobble
}{}{\failure}%
\makeatother
```

Additionally `bgcolor` is implemented as a colorbox and therefore is incompatible with linebreaking. You can avoid this by applying the background color as a highlight with `lua-ul` instead. Then you get the document

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{xcolor,luacolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lua-ul}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\definecolor{bg}{rgb}{0.85, 0.85, 0.85}

\makeatletter
% Patch minted to allow breakanywhere for mininline
\patchcmd \minted@inputpyg {%
  \FancyVerbFormatLine
}{%
  \FancyVerbFormatLine{%
    % \FV@BreakByTokenAnywhereHook
    \strut\FancyVerbFormatText{\FancyVerbBreakStart##1\FancyVerbBreakStop}\strut%
  }%
  \@gobble
}{}{\failure}%

% Wrap \mintinline to apply color through highlighting
\NewDocumentCommand\specialMintinline{O{} m v} {
  \highLight[bg]{%
    \mintinline[breaklines,breakanywhere,#1]{#2}{#3}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\setmonofont{Courier New}
\begin{document}
    Hello world
    
    \specialMintinline{text}{aVeryLongStringaVeryLongStringaVeryLongStringaVeryLongStringaVeryLongStringaVeryLongStringaVeryLongStringaVeryLongString}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to get rid of the inverted L character at the end of each line? I tried resetting `breaksymbolright` but that didn't work...

Comment: You have to reset `breakanywheresymbolpre`, but be advised that then you can't determine anymore if there should be spaces between lines based on the output.

Comment: Ok, I modified your code to `\mintinline[breakanywheresymbolpre=,breaklines,breakanywhere,#1]{#2}{#3}%` and that seems to work OK. Not sure what you mean by determination of spaces between lines. Are you referring to vertical space or horizontal space?

Comment: @user32882 If one line ends with `foo` and the next one starts with `bar`, then you don't know if the original text was `foobar` or `foo bar`.