codeblock does not break across lines
I am trying to create codeblocks with colored backgrounds in regular text. However, long strings do not break across lines and extend past the margins.
Is it possible to add an additional option to the following MWE to permit computer code to break across lines?
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% define the background color
\definecolor{codeblock}{RGB}{240,240,240} % light gray, code background

% define the codeblock section using \lstinline
\newcommand{\coded}[1]{\colorbox{codeblock}{\lstinline|#1|}}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\lipsum[1] \\

\noindent
If you set the \coded{action-shutdown} statement and do not specify the \coded{recovery-timeout} 
statement, the interfaces through which violations occur are shut down when the 
following conditions occur and the following items happen \coded{storm control level exceeds the set 
level}. They do not recover automatically from the port-error condition. You must issue the 
\coded{clear ethernet-switching recovery-timeout} command to clear the port error and 
restore the interfaces to service. \\

\noindent
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}

Here is an example of what I am talking about that I was able to render in PDF:


use listings options. don't put it into a box else it can't be broken. that's the point of boxes.

Forgive my ignorance, but I have tried using the listings package, but to no avail. You will note I had it as one of the installed packages listed. Can you reference an example? I have been looking online, but most examples are too extreme for my needs.

You could adopt the idea from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/656034/36296 and use lua-ul to add highlighting:
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{luacolor}
\usepackage{lua-ul}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\NewDocumentCommand\specialMintinline{v} {%
  \highLight[lightgray!30]{%
    \mintinline[breaklines,breakanywhere]{text}{#1}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1] 

If you set the \specialMintinline{action-shutdown} statement and do not specify the \specialMintinline{recovery-timeout} 
statement, the interfaces through which violations occur are shut down when the following conditions occur and the following items happen \specialMintinline{storm control level exceeds the set level}. They do not recover automatically from the port-error condition. You must issue the \specialMintinline{clear ethernet-switching recovery-timeout} command to clear the port error and 
restore the interfaces to service. 


\lipsum[1]

\end{document}



I will try this out. Thanks! I have been wanting to do more with LuaTeX. Seems like a potentially powerful tool.

@KerryCox You're welcome!

This works very nice. The nproblem is that I am also trying to get additional developers to adopt my LaTeX scripts into their existingMarkdown files. I am trying to keep everything simple as some have a hard enough time using the proper Markdown commands. Any time I can push scripts down to a template and reduce the LaTeX-centric commands, I try and do so. Hence, I adopted the strategy of using \texttt{{} for ALL teletype code. But your solution is really good. and I may end up using it elsewhere. Thanks again!

I figured out an alternative method by changing my \texttt command to use renewcommand:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}

\definecolor{Light}{gray}{.90}
\definecolor{codeblock}{RGB}{255,252,246} % light beige, code background
\sethlcolor{codeblock}


\let\OldTexttt\texttt
\renewcommand{\texttt}[1]{\OldTexttt{\hl{#1}}}% will affect all \texttt
%\newcommand{\hltexttt}[1]{\texttt{\hl{#1}}}% comment above \renewcommand if want this

\begin{document}
    Normal text \texttt{foo bar} normal text.
    
    More normal text plus \texttt{shaded code} plus normal text. 
\end{document}

This way all my existing \texttt{commands} show up with a colored background by using the soul package.
Credit goes ot the following page: Adding a highlight to \texttt blocks

You could've just used \newcommand\coded[1]{\texttt{\hl{#1}}} instead without (potentially) breaking all other \texttt usages. And if you're using LuaTeX you should really use lua-ul instead of soul.

Thanks @Skillmon. I would love to start using LuaTeX, but have never tried it out. I know it would do several other things that I want to try out, but my forays into using  it have not been very successful. I want all my \texttt{} instances this way, so I am fine with this.
